# How Do I Connect OpenCart To Bank of America Merchant Services with FirstData/PayEezy?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, firstdata, payeezy

I need to connect OpenCart to Bank of America Merchant Services which uses FirstData/PayEezy:

https://merch.bankofamerica.com/global-gateway-e4-features

I'm guessing I need an extension for that? Do you know which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look around the Opencart Marketplace and you can find [extensions](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=firstdata) to add FirstData support to your opencart site.  Using one of those would allow you to not have to figure out FirstData's API.

Comment: Does that work with Bank of America Merchant Services?

Comment: There are ones listed that support Global Gateway e4, which is what BoA is saying they use.  Those should work.